# Select in select statement (Join Table) SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, group-by, left-join

What select statement I should use to get the result as below:

[image: I want this]

Currently when i run my stored procedure below, it will display the "Result" image:

```
select vm.ID_Vendor,vm.Vendor_Name,vpe.Company_Name,vpe.TOTAL,
vpe.COUNT,vpe.AVERAGE from VENDOR_MASTER vm
LEFT JOIN
(select vvd.ID_Vendor,sc.ID_Company,sc.Company_Name,vvd.VPE_Average_Score,
SUM(vvd.VPE_Average_Score) AS TOTAL,COUNT(vvd.VPE_Total_Score) AS COUNT,
(SUM(vvd.VPE_Average_Score)/COUNT(vvd.VPE_Total_Score)) AS AVERAGE,
vvm.Assessor_Name FROM VENDOR_VPE_MASTER vvm
left join VENDOR_VPE_DETAIL vvd on vvm.ID_VPE_Master=vvd.ID_VPE_Master
left join SETUP_COMPANY sc on vvm.ID_Company=sc.ID_Company
left join REF_EVL_RATING rer1 on vvd.Quality_Product=rer1.ID_Evl_Rating
left join REF_EVL_RATING rer2 on vvd.Service=rer2.ID_Evl_Rating
left join REF_EVL_RATING rer3 on vvd.Technical=rer3.ID_Evl_Rating
left join REF_EVL_RATING rer4 on vvd.Quality_Mgmt=rer4.ID_Evl_Rating
left join REF_EVL_RATING rer5 on vvd.Price=rer5.ID_Evl_Rating
GROUP BY vvd.ID_Vendor,sc.ID_Company,sc.Company_Name,vvd.VPE_Average_Score,
vvd.VPE_Average_Score,vvd.VPE_Total_Score,vvm.Assessor_Name) as vpe on vm.ID_Vendor=vpe.ID_Vendor
order by vpe.ID_Vendor
```

[image: Result]

Comment: sorry about that, it is not about formatting spreadsheets or writing headers vertically. it just I want the store procedure that can be retrieve the result that I want.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It seems now that you want to change your GROUP By clause, see my comment below

This is not possible as the SQL Server Management Studio is about the data and server management, it's not made to create reports or export well-formatted data (as said in the comments). However, if you have Excel installed, you can execute the query from Excel (Data -> Get External Data). This allows you to format the headers as you want and it is easier to export to other formats (PDF, images, ...). 
As an alternative, you could use Reporting Services where you have a lot of possibilities for these things. However, the Excel solution will be easier to implement if you only need vertical headers.

Comment: sorry about that, it is not about formatting spreadsheets or writing headers vertically. it just I want the store procedure that can be retrieve the result that I want.

Comment: Ok, as I understand now you just want to change the grouping of your results? To get from your result to the one desired, it should be enough to exclude company_name and aggregate over the other columns (sum/average).